# Is there any faster way to webscrap tables using python pandas.read_html?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, web-scraping

I am using `pandas.read_html` to scrape the tables from a website having over 9000 pages.
My code (dummy) is:

```
table_df = pd.DataFrame([])
urls = [list of urls]
for url in urls:
   table = pd.read_html(url)
   temp = table[0]
   table_df = pd.concat([table_df,temp],axis=0)
   time.sleep(np.randint(5,10))
```

For the first few iterations, I am getting 9.57s per iteration.

At this speed, it will take more than 1 day to complete the iterations. Can I do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

There are too many unknowns here to conclude the `read_html` is taking the time.

There is a sleep for 5-10 seconds in the above code. Let's take the average of 7.5. This means the timing of each iteration being 9.57 seconds but 7.5 seconds, on average is sleeping. So 2 seconds for the read and concat.  I assume the sleep is in there to avoid some request limiter and you know it needs to be between 5 and 10 seconds. This is 80% of the time.

Next, the concat. How much time does this take?

Next the `read_html`. Is the time being spent in the http communication, vpns, proxies, etc or in the converting the HTML to the dataframe? You can do some timing to narrow this down if needed.

If there is 1 second (guessing) in communication overhead and 7.5 seconds, on average sleeping, then 1 second handles the html parsing, converting, concating. Lots of data type conversions, parsing html, dataframe creation, etc. Sounds reasonable.

Also look at the [gotchas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-html-gotchas) and the [flavor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html). Is the html strictly correct so that lxml can be used? If not, then there is an lxml failure, which will take time, then html5lib gets called. If you know the html is not strictly valid, you can jump to html5lib.

If that speed is not enough, you can write your own html to dataframe using the requests module. Then you can skip the parts of the pages that you are not interested in. Maybe you can speed this up. But pandas uses libraries that are optimized for this task so maybe not.

A way that will save very small amount of time (pre-mature optimization is the root of all evil) is instead of concating in the loop, append the dataframe to a list. Then concat the list of dataframes after the loop is done. But, in this case, the savings here seem small. 80% is sleeping. Some time in communication. Time in parsing.